# Change productname in cart, quote, invoice Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, observers

I need to change the productname visible for the customer after adding it to the cart. Also it should show on invoice, order email and everything else visible for the customer.

I made an extension with observer checkout_cart_product_add_after

```
   $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');            
   $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
   $item->getProduct()->setName('this is the productname');
   $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

But the original productname is still visible on minicart, cartpage, etc.

The 'add to cart message' is the only place where the new changed productname is visible. What should I change?

Answer (score 3):

use this event "sales_quote_item_set_product"
and in observer set name like this:

```
/* For minicart and cart */
$item->getProduct()->setName('Custom Name');
/* For checkout page cart items */
$item->setName('Custom  Name');
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: HI @Amit Saini,

Above solution is working perfect on cart, minicart, checkout shipping page but when we go to checkout payment page, again default product name show. When we click on next after select shipping method, magento update quote_item table and checkout payment page show default product name, how can we stop this update?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solutions myself.

Hope this helps anyone searching for it, or if you have comments how it could be done a better way, please let me know.

Created a plugin with this code:

```
class Item 
{
    public function afterSetProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
        $result
    ){
        $subject->setName('New Name');
    }
}
```

So this sets a new name to the quote item, visible in everything, excepting cart and mini cart.

Now I have got my new productname visible in:
- Added to cart message
- Quote-item, even in admin and invoices

But not in:
- Mini cart
- Cartpage

For the cart page:

I changed output of function getProduct in Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer:

```
class Renderer
{
    public function afterGetProductName(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer $subject,
        $result
    ){
        return 'this is the name';
    }
}
```

For minicart, also with plugin:

```
class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData(
     \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ){
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $data['product_name'] = 'this is the productname';
        return $data;    
}
```